# Can eclipse connect Java editing to JSF files, and if yes, how to enable it?

Tags: eclipse, jsf

In using Eclipse to edit a web application. When I edit a Java class, put the cursor into a method name and use “search for references” from the mouse menu, Eclipse shows me all other places in the Java code, where the method is used. When I rename the method in one Java class, the rename is executed all across the code in any other Java classes where the method is used.

However, in our web application, there are also HTML files in JSF-XML format (EL), and they can also use the Java code. Example:

```java
// BaseForm.java
@Named("BaseForm")
@SessionScoped
public class BaseForm
    public String getMessage() {
       return "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- baseForm.xhtml -->
<ui:composition ...>
    <ui:define name="contentHeader">
        <h3>#{BaseForm.message}</h3>
                       ^^^^^^^ this will invoke getMessage()!
```

Eclipse does detects the connection between the Java and the HTML: If there is no `BaseForm`, or if `BaseForm` doesn’t have a `getMessage()`, it will show an error in the HTML editor.

I am not editing the HTML files normally, I am only working on the Java code. But, if I rename something, it maybe that the rename must be aligned with a change somewhere in the HTML. I often miss this, and it doesn’t get noticed until a user clicks on the page where the error is, and the application crashes. (So to say, there is no compile-time error.) My question is, **is there any support for me in Eclipse when renaming, and if yes, how can I enable it?**

My **observed behaviour** is, when I “search for references”, Eclipes gives me only the matches in Java, not in HTML (even though it knows something about the relationship of the two, as I wrote before.) If I rename `getMessage()`, for example to `getFallbackMessage()`, it will change all function calls in all Java classes, taking into account many kinds of dependencies such as inheritance, and not accidentally renaming an unrelated `getMessage()` function that belongs to another class. So this is more powerful than a text editor’s Edit/Replace in all files. However, Eclipse doesn’t change the HTML where the function is called.

I could imagine that, if the one part of this function is so elaborated, that there is also some support to port such renames to HTML, but it doesn’t yet. I wonder if that exists and if yes, how can I enable it.

My **desired behaviour** is, when I “search for references”, Eclipse shows me references in Java files and references in XHTML files. When I rename `getMessage()` to `getFallbackMessage()`, the HTML will be edited, and `#{FormClass.message}` will be changed to `#{FormClass.fallbackMessage}`.

**So my question is composed in two parts:**

- **does such function exist in Eclipse?**
- **if yes,** what may cause that it is disabled, and **how maybe I can change it to be enabled?**

Comment: A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is missing and the question should be asked in a more professional manner, avoiding terms like _poor_, not telling irrelevant stuff and focusing on the problem instead.

Comment: Please excuse me for my badly-formed question. I formulated the question longer and clearer now.